# How to unite several models into one?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've created two models and now it's need to be united in one.
Both of them are inheriting QAbstractListModel and contains only roles and simple data as `QVector<QMap<..., ...>>` backing; what I pass to data() function

There's any way to unite them into one model and pass to Qml page through delegate?

Here my models:

ExtraModel

```
#include "extramodel.h"

ExtraModel::ExtraModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
QMap<QString, QString> element;

element.insert("SimpleText", "Hello, world!");
backing.append(element);
element.clear();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ExtraModel::roleNames() const
{
QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

roles[SimpleTextRole] = "SimpleText";

return roles;
}

QVariant ExtraModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
if(role == SimpleTextRole)
    return backing[index.row()].value("SimpleText");
}
```

MainModel (here I am trying to pass ExtraModel to MainModel)

```
#include <mainmodel.h>
#include <extramodel.h>

MainModel::MainModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
ExtraModel *extra;
QMap<QString, QHash<int, QByteArray>> element;

element.insert("Role", extra->roleNames());
backing.append(element);
element.clear();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> MainModel::roleNames() const
{
QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

roles[ModelRole] = "Role";

return roles;
}

QVariant MainModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
if (role == ModelRole)
    return backing[index.row()].value("Role");

return QVariant();
}
```

That's how I want it to be in .qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import Sailfish.Silica 1.0
import MainModel 1.0

Page {
  SilicaListView {
    model: MainModel {
      id: _mainModel
    }
    delegate: Rectangle {
      Text { 
        id: _simpleText

        text: _mainModel.[someRoleNameFromExtraModel].SimpleText
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add to the question in what sense the two models correlate? Is it simply a union (with the same roles) or more complex? (maybe add a visual explanaition)

Comment: @Amfasis, thanks for your reply. 
Two models are should be in one general model and then I want to have a possibility to use them in different views using one general model.
Yes, it's more complex union with different roles.

Comment: In case of very simple union, you could probably get away with a straightforward proxy model, but in any case you will have to write it yourself

Comment: what is proxy model and how can I use it to place two models in one another? Maybe, easy example of code? It would be very helpful

Comment: There is QSortFilterProxyModel, but actually I don't think it fits. So you have to write another QAbstractListModel which proxies the two models in the way you see fit. However, without further details on your data you won't see any helpfull answers

Comment: It might actually be more worthwhile to rewrite you two datasources directly as one, but that depends on the usecase

Comment: @Amfasis  "So you have to write another QAbstractListModel which proxies the two models in the way you see fit" that's exactly what I am trying to do :)
but it  doesn't work now. I tried to send my models using simple backing and roles. I've attached my models to the question

Comment: This way you are returning the rolenames when requesting the `ModelRole`. Are you looking for a hierarchical model where each row in MainModel has child's from ExtraModel?

Comment: @Amfasis before I've been trying just to pass an ExtraModel to roles in MainModel, but it didn't work, so I decided to try to pass roleNames, that also doesn't work

Comment: no, the rolenames should go in the function roleNames(). I sincerely don't understand what your desired end-goal is

Comment: @Amfasis I am just trying to pass ExtraModel's data (or ExtraModel itself) to MainModel. And then, I want to use ExtraModel's data through MainModel in .qml page. Is that possible to implement? I've written about ExtraModel only, but there will be more than one model

Comment: Please make a textual summarising representation of the expected data rows and/or a visual representation (using something like paint.net) of how you want it shown on screen and attach it so the question.

Comment: @Amfasis I've attached .qml page example. I think it doesn't make sence to draw something as simple as this. As result, I want to have possibility use SimpleTextRole's data from ExtraModel, using MainModel.

Comment: ok, for me it makes more sense to make the MainModel a plain model (C++ class with `Q_PROPERTY(ExtraModel ...)` ). Did you specifically avoid that option?

Comment: @Amfasis nope. I don't know Qt possibilities that well (I am new in it), so I am not sure how can I use QProperty to collect and use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better of writing a plain class with Q_PROPERTY to `ExtraModel`

```
class MainModel : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ExtraModel* extra READ extraModel CONSTANT)

  public:
    MainModel();
    ExtraModel* extraModel() const { return extraModel_; }

  private:
    ExtraModel* extraModel_ = nullptr;
};
```

cpp file:

```
MainModel::MainModel(QObject *parent) 
    : QObject(parent)
    , extraModel_(new ExtraModel(this))
{
}
```

Then your QML will look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import Sailfish.Silica 1.0
import MainModel 1.0

Page {
  MainModel {
    id: _mainModel
  }
  SilicaListView {
    id: _mainModelView
    model: _mainModel.extra

    delegate: Rectangle { 
      Text { 
        id: _simpleText

        text: simpleText
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, you should also change the rolenames to be uncapitalized for the first letter:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> ExtraModel::roleNames() const
{
    return {
        {SimpleTextRole, "simpleText"},
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example you send! Really helpful. I will try it. But I have one more question just to ensure if am I right: if I want to implement more than one model (like, ExtraModel, ExtraModel1, ... etc), will that right to create more properties inside .h,  and more constructors inside .cpp file? Like 

... 
    : QObject(parent)
    , extraModel_(new ExtraModel(this))
{
}

... 
    : QObject(parent)
    , extraModel1_(new ExtraModel1(this))
{
}
....

or it'll be better to use something like map<int, QObject*>? 
Or maybe both are wrong?

Comment: You can indeed add Q_PROPERTY and the extraModel2(new ExtraModel2(this)) in constructor and all the other stuff duplicates as well

Comment: thank you very much again! I've already figured out and implemented.

Comment: @Anfasis can I bother you one more time? I've added signal to my ExtraModel (). How can I pass it to .qml page using MainModel? I've tried to use _mainModel.extra as component like I did before to call onSelectedChanged but it doesn't work as component.

Comment: You need to use `Connections` object. But please ask a question (or search first) since this is a different subject, so I will not edit the answer for this